# Передача параметра в контроллер Spring

Tags: spring-boot, controller, аутентификация

Есть приложение с авторизацией на токенах
Есть метод контроллера

```
@PostMapping(value = "{userId}/rate/inc")
public Double incRate(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    return service.incUserRate(userId);
}
```

Можно ли добавить какой то фильтр что бы этот фильтр получал юзера по текущему токену и передавал его дальше в метод? 
Как то так:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/rate/inc")
public Double incRate(User user) {
    service.incUserRate(user);
}
```

И как будет правильнее? Использовать токены только для аутентификации? Или же можно их еще задействовать для получения юзера без использования `{userId}`

Comment: Я сделал фильтр который проверяет есть ли токен и, если он есть пытается авторизовать пользователя. После успешной авторизации в контроллере можно добавить параметр `Principal principal` из которого можно получить имя пользователя и потом уже сделать запрос к базе.